# Setting step-size with Locator and Manipulate in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, manipulators

Given this Mathematica code,

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

How do I set the step distance on the locator?  And if possible, constrain them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, p}], 
  PlotRange -> 2], {{p, {1, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.4, 0.5}, Locator}]
```

which would restrict the locator to a rectangular lattice with a horizontal spacing of 0.4 and a vertical spacing of 0.5. The range of the coordinates for the locator is specified by `{xmin,ymin} = {-1,-1}` and `{xmax, ymax} = {1,1}`.

---

If you want more flexibility, e.g. you want to restrict the position of locator to a non-rectangular lattice or to a more general set of coordinates you could do something like

```
Manipulate[
 With[{tab = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {40, 2}]}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[p, (p = Nearest[tab, #][[1]]) &], 
   Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[p]}], {Red, Point /@ tab}}, PlotRange -> 2]]],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, ControlType -> None}]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's great, but I am actually more interested in setting the step size :)

Comment: @James: do you mean setting the step size dynamically with a slider or such?

Comment: @James The vertical and horizontal step sizes are in the `{0.4, 0.5}` part in the code above. As I understood your question that's what you were looking for, weren't you?

Comment: @Heike I hadn't noticed that you already had step size in your answer so I removed my answer.

Comment: Ah, I got it.  I ended up using something very similar to this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate&lang=en) states:

```
Manipulate[expr, {u, umin, umax, du}]
```

allows the value of *u* to vary between *umin* and *umax* in steps *du*.

and

```
Manipulate[expr, {u, {u1, u2, u3,...}}]
```

allows *u* to take on discrete values.

One of these approaches should work for you.

Comment: Yeah, but I cannot make sense of how to use it with Locator, which is kind of my problem.

Comment: The Locator has an x and y position - you would set these separately? Unfortunately I have to go to work now so can't help further until this evening my timezone.

Comment: I've tried every possible combination I could think of.  I just gave up and brought it here.  Next I go to Wolfram!  :)